# what are the steps to install prediction IO on windows 7

Tags: java, apache, predictionio

i am new to predictionio and i am not able to install the predictionio on my PC. The steps given on the apache site i am not able to understand command like 
$ tar zxvf apache-predictionio-0.12.1.tar.gz
$ gpg --verify apache-predictionio-0.12.1.tar.gz.asc apache-predictionio-0.12.1.tar.gz
.
.
.
which are given on site document
 can  you please provide step by step installation for windows.

Comment: You can try the [docker installation](https://predictionio.apache.org/community/projects/#docker-installation-for-predictionio).

Comment: Check the comments..https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/predictionio-user/OmrjfcG7msQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Prediction.io engine is meant to be installed in a **Linux** environment.

If you only have Windows available, you could download a VM manager, say Oracle's [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/), setup a Linux distro, [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/) is fairly easy to use.

There's plenty of ressources online to do those steps.

Then follow along with the documentation of prediction.io, and it will work like a charm !

---

Or as @McMutton mentionned, a [Docker](https://predictionio.apache.org/community/projects/#docker-installation-for-predictionio) installation documentation is also available.